# How to send data to ActionBean via JavaScript?

Tags: java, javascript, stripes

I'm playing with Stripes and I wonder if it is possible to send Javascript generated data to ActionBean. To be more specific, when I click with my mouse on certain element on page, I want to send ID of that element back to ActionBean after clicking on `stripes:link`. Providing I already have that ID saved in a JS variable `id`, how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using parameterised link?

```
<stripes:link id="mylink" href/beanclass="..." event="...">
   <stripes:param name="id" value="some_default_value"/>
   Click on me!
</stripes:link>
```

Which would most probably generate: `http://mysite.com/...?id=some_default_value`, which you would later use javascript to change `some_default_value` to the `id` you want?

***Note***: Suggestion unverified.  I've no dev tool installed on this old lappie.

**Edit**: On second thought, why not just write some javascript to append `"?id=" + id;` to the link's url address?

Answer (score 1):

create a hidden input element in your html

```
<input type="hidden" name="?" id="?" />
```

use javascript to set the value of it

```
document.getElementById("?").value = ??;
```

and the value will be posted with your form submission.

Comment: Just tried it, but it doesn't work. Maybe it would if I was using form, but I want to run event via link. Any ideas?

Comment: yes that would only work with a form. i'll leave it to someone else to explain how to do it without a form as it would be a bit more of a hack.